# Can I add a property or state into Next JS Router like React-Route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I would like to know if it's possible to add a state inside a Router.router [link](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html) using Next.JS.

I know how to handle router.query but i don't want to show the state on that query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

later you will be able to access that state in the `location` object.

see:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

---

Edit: with Next JS's Link component it is a bit more limited. you could utilize the `as` prop.

```
<Link href="/dashboard?from=loginPage" as="/dashboard" />
```

only `/dashboard` will be shown in the URL, you will still have access to `from=loginPage` in the query. You will have to serialize your state to a query string (and values will become string.

here's a quick example:

in Nav:

```
<Link href='/?from=navClick' as="/">
  <a>Home</a>
</Link>
```

In the home component (which renders on '/')

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Home = () => {
  const { query } = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      {query.from ? `You are from: ${query.from}` : 'Well met.'}
    </>
  );
};
```

If the user goes to the home page by clicking on that link, you will get the from value in the `query` object, however it won't be rendered in the browser's address bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it's a little bit deeper, I'm not using a link and im not using react-router. Im using next js router.

Comment: Hi @hiad - sorry, I've added an example of that in the answer. basically you could use the `as` prop to "hide" the query params from your users.